# WSDL2Java in Ant

Tags: maven, ant, wsdl, wsdl2java

What is the exact way of generating a Java code using WSDL in a ant build file? There were so many ways given, but most of them are not reorganized by Ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Axis Ant Task](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/ant/ant.html) for this. There is also [CXF way of doing things](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html). I would use Apache CXF, like this:

```
<target name="cxfWSDLToJava">
  <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
    <arg value="-client"/>
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="src"/>
    <arg value="MyWSDL.wsdl"/>
    <classpath>
      <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
  </java>
</target>
```

Comment: I have configured it like this,

Comment: <target name="cxfWSDLToJava" depends ="init ">
      <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
         <arg value="-client"/>
         <arg value="-d"/>
  <arg value="${classes}"/>
         <arg value="src/main/resources/hello_world_async.wsdl"/>
         <classpath>
     <path location="${dependencies}/cxf-bundle_2.5.2.wso2v1.jar"/>
         </classpath>
      </java>

Comment: It gives the following exception, is there a error in class-path ? [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/context/Context
     [java]  at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.AbstractGenerator.<init>(AbstractGenerator.java:46)
     [java]  at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AbstractJAXWSGenerator.<init>(AbstractJAXWSGenerator.java:30)..........

Comment: Found the error, it was version problems of the cxf dependencies. Now it is OK. Thanks